# GIT-SCM bash.exe doesn't work from "Enter-PSSession -Computer myServer"?

Tags: powershell, git, remoting

Let's suppose I download and install Git-SCM on a remote windows 10 computer using this installer:

```
https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.33.1.windows.1/PortableGit-2.33.1-64-bit.7z.exe
```

I unzip this exe installation file to the directory C:\GitPortable on the computer myserver.  Which means on this computer I can start bash from powershell by typing:

```
PS> $env:path = "C:\PortableGit\usr\bin;$env:path"

PS> bash
dude@myserver ~
$ 
$ # now i'm at a BASH shell prompt!
```

Now, for my problem.  I want to Enter-PSSession from another computer on my network, and start BASH shell from the remote interactive powershell session. But, it doesn't work even though bash.exe is a command line program.  Example:

```
PS> Enter-PSSession -Computer MyServer

[myServer]: PS>  $env:path = "C:\PortableGit\usr\bin;$env:path"

[myServer]: PS>  bash
<NO OUTPUT HERE?>

[myServer]: PS>  cd C:\PortableGit\usr\bin

[myServer]: PS>  dir bash.exe

-a----         8/24/2021   6:24 AM        1963639 bash.exe

[myServer]: PS>  .\bash.exe
<NO OUTPUT HERE?>
[myServer]: PS>
```

However, bash works if I put "--help":

```
[myServer]: PS> bash --help
GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release-(x86_64-pc-msys)
Usage:  /usr/bin/bash [GNU long option] [option] ...
        /usr/bin/bash [GNU long option] [option] script-file ...
GNU long options:
        --debug
        --debugger
        --dump-po-strings
        ...
```

I really needed to interactive bash shell from Enter-PSSession to work..  are their any work arounds to get an interactive bash shell to work remotely?

Comment: The Git developers said that you potentially need to use winpty, so instead of "[myserver]: PS> bash", it would be "[myserver]: PS> winpty bash --login --interactive."   Unfortunately, this gives the error message.   "winpty : stdin is not a tty
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (stdin is not a tty:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48199794/winpty-and-git-bash